# How to filter group column header in ui-grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

Is there a way to filter the format of the header in ui-grid grouping. Please refer to the following image:[image]

After clicking the group, refer to the next image..[image]

Is there a way to filter the format and convert it to say: 12/04/2016 13-31-30?